# Initialize javaScript engine in apache camel

Tags: javascript, apache-camel

I have a javascript file (continaing some function definitions). I would like to include the file javascript into the engine used by Camel within my routes (ideally i would prefer this be done once for the whole Camel context.

Is there any way to do this ? If so how ?

I would like to do something like:

```
<route>
   <from uri="direct:example" />
   <to uri="jdbc:mydb" />
   <setBody>
       <javaScript>
           var b = {
               "name":    wrapname(body.get("name")),
               "country": wrapcountry(body.get("country"))
           }
           JSON.stringify(b); 
       </javaScript>
   </setBody>
</route>
```

Where `wrapname` and `wrapcountry` are functions defined in the javaScript file I'd like to import. (These may be used in different routes).

An auxilary question is when is the javaScript engine initialized in Camel (once globally, for each javaScript expression) ?

Thanks,
Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

as of Camel 2.11, you can load a script from an external resources

> You can externalize the script and have Camel load it from a resource
>   such as "classpath:", "file:", or "http:". This is done using the
>   following syntax: "resource:scheme:location", eg to refer to a file on
>   the classpath you can do:

see http://camel.apache.org/javascript.html for details

Comment: Yeah! So I,m looking forward to the release of 2.11 ;) Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Externalize the javascript code to a "js" file. For example,
test-javascript.js would contain

```js
var content = request.getBody().toString().toUpperCase();
var substring = "CAMEL";
if (content.indexOf(substring) !== -1) {
 request.setHeader("uppercase", "true");
} else {
 request.setHeader("uppercase", "false");
}
request.setBody(content);
```

And the camel route that uses this externalized javascript file would look like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start" />
        <log message="Got1 ${body}" />
        <setBody >
            <constant>Test message through camel route</constant>
        </setBody>
         <to uri="language://javascript:classpath:test-javascript.js?transform=false" />
         <to uri="log:javascript?showAll=true"/>        
        <log message="Got2 ${body}" />
        <log message="Got3 ${header.uppercase}" />
 </route>
</routes>
```

It produces the output such as

[main] INFO route1 - Got2 TEST MESSAGE THROUGH CAMEL ROUTE
[main] INFO route1 - Got3 true